# Apopt Documentation

Tags: python, gekko

I am looking for documentation about the solver APOPT. I used Gekko for my thesis and therefore I have to quote and explain every part of the code. Are there videos/articles/websites that explain how the solver works? Does it use Branch and Bound to solve the optimization problems?
APOPT is always described as a solver for non-linear MIP? Is it also suitable for linear MIP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APOPT is a Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming (MINLP) solver. It can also solve Mixed Integer Linear Programming (MILP) problems as well as Nonlinear Programming (NLP), and Linear Programming (LP) problems. It is an active-set sequential quadratic programming (SQP) solver that uses Branch and Bound to solve mixed integer problems. There is more information on APOPT at the following:

- Web-site [apopt.com](https://apopt.com/download.php)
- [Wikipedia (APOPT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APOPT)
- Hedengren, J.D., Mojica, J.L., Cole, W., Edgar, T.F., APOPT: MINLP Solver for Differential Algebraic Systems with Benchmark Testing, INFORMS Annual Meeting, Phoenix, AZ, Oct 2012.
- In [publications of APMonitor and Gekko](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/APMonitorReferences) such as:
- Hedengren, J. D. and Asgharzadeh Shishavan, R., Powell, K.M., and Edgar, T.F., Nonlinear Modeling, Estimation and Predictive Control in APMonitor, Computers and Chemical Engineering, Volume 70, pg. 133–148, 2014, doi: 10.1016/j.compchemeng.2014.04.013.
- Beal, L.D.R., Hill, D., Martin, R.A., and Hedengren, J. D., GEKKO Optimization Suite, Processes, Volume 6, Number 8, 2018, doi: 10.3390/pr6080106.